# Replace WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Spring boot for ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

Since Spring Boot 2.7.x version `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class is deprecated and there is a [guide](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) from spring.io on how to replace those classes and use component-based security configuration.

My question is how to handle the following use-case:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class BearerAuthWebSecurityConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(null);
        resources.authenticationManager(new OAuth2AuthenticationManager());
    }
    
}
```

I did not find any guide on how to handle `@EnableResourceServer` and `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` using the new component-based security configuration. And under the hood these classes also use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and should be moved to the component-based security configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer` is from the [EOL'd `spring-security-oauth` project](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-oauth#spring-security-oauth-is-no-longer-actively-maintained-by-vmware-inc), therefore there is no support for new features/deprecations. I recommend you to use [Spring Security's support for OAuth 2.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html).